# Countable admissible ordinals

Tags: computability-theory, lo.logic, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, model-theory

Jensen claimed that for any finite increasing sequence countable admissible  ordinals $\omega= \alpha_0<\alpha_1\cdots <\alpha_n$, there is a real $x$ so that, for each $m\leq n$, $\alpha_m$ is the $m+1$-th admissible ordinal relative to $x$.

Anybody knows the proof? Or where to find it?

Comment: http://www.mathematik.hu-berlin.de/~raesch/org/jensen.html
(The paper titled "Admissible sets")

Comment: Thanks. It's really painful to read the handwritten manuscripts...

Comment: (I just emailed you a typeset version of the notes.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a model theoretic proof of the generalization to countable sequences which appears in a paper by Simpson and Weitkamp.

High and low Kleene degrees of coanalytic sets
Stephen G. Simpson & Galen Weitkamp
Journal of Symbolic Logic 48 (2):356-368 (1983)

I believe that this proof is due to Harrington, based on Jensen's and Friedman's model theoretic proof of Sacks's theorem that every countable admissible ordinal is the least admissible relative to some real.

Comment: Hi Ted, nice to see you here!

Comment: Yes, Ted, welcome to MathOverflow.

Comment: Ted, thanks. In Simpon-Weitkamp's paper, it is claimed that Harrington has a model theoretical proof. But where to find it?

Comment: I asked Prof. Jensen, when he was in NUS, whether he has a model theoretical proof, or by applying Barwise compactness, of his result. He said no. So I guess Harrington's proof must be highly nontrivial.

Comment: Yu, the result is Theorem 4.1 of the Simpson and Weitkamp paper and they include a proof.  The proof comes before the attribution to Harrington.

Comment: Ted, you are right. But the proof heavily depends on Jensen's theorem. Actually in the proof of Lemma 4.3, they need Lemma 3.3 that is Jensen's result. 